# codeigniter ajax modal form validation error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Im working on a simple codeigniter modal form validation i want to validate the data that being inputted from the modal before inserting it into the database but im having difficulty in getting the validation error it doesn't show the error when i click the button add

this is my controller

```
public function insert_validation()
{
    $this->form->set_rules('faculty_name', 'name', 'required|trim');
    $this->form->set_rules('email_address','email','required|valid_email');
    $this->form->set_rules('password','password','required');

    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $array = array(
            'success' => '<div class="alert alert-success">Faculty Member Added</div>'
           );
    }
    else
    {
        $array = array(
            'error' => true,
            'name_error' => form_error('name'),
            'email_error' => form_error('email'),
            'password_error' => form_error('password'),
        );

    }
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

this is my view

```
    <form method="post" id="insert_form">

            <div class="modal fade" id="Modal_Add" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add New Faculty</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span id="success_message"></span>
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label"><b>Faculty Name</b></label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                          <input type="text" name="faculty_name" id="faculty_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <span id="name_error" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label"><b>Email Address</b></label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                          <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                        </div>
                        <span id="email_error" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-md-4 col-form-label"><b>Password</b></label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                          <input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <span id="password_error" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" type="submit" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

this is my script

```
$('#insert_form').on('submit',function(event)){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url()?>pages/insert_validation",
                method:"POST",
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                dataType:"json",
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('#btn_add').attr('disabled','disabled');
                },
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data.name_error);
                    if(data.error)
                    {
                        if(data.name_error != '')
                        {
                            $('#name_error').html(data.name_error);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#name_error').html('');
                        }
                        if(data.email_error != '')
                        {
                            $('#email_error').html(data.email_error);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#email_error').html('');
                        }
                        if(data.password_error != '')
                        {
                            $('#password_error').html(data.password_error);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#password_error').html('');
                        }
                    }
                    if(data.success)
                    {
                        $('success_message').html(data.success);
                        $('#name_error').html('');
                        $('#email_error').html('');
                        $('#password_error').html('');
                        $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
                    }
                    $('#btn_add').attr('disabled',false);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in developer console(tools)?? What is it returning??

Comment: `alert(data.name_error);` this line definitely give you an error if your validation was successful. Because in success method you don't have an array index `name_error`. Please comment that line and check if that works.

Comment: Try to have the same indexes in both the conditions. Just that in the success condition keep those indexes empty or false.